# Is there a way to read HTML file in python and pass the parameters and sent it through mail?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read HTML file and attaching it to msg.set_content(file, subtype='html') and implemented few {name} parameters inside HTML file. Is there a way to workaround this issue?

```
def send_html(send_to=None, subject=None):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Thank You!'
    msg['From'] = 'abc@abc.com'
    msg['To'] = send_to
    with open("thankyou.html", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
       message= f.read()
    msg.set_content(message, subtype='html')
    send(msg)
    return "Email with html sent"
```

inside HTML file, thankyou.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>{name}, Thank you for registering</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `message = message.format(name=name)`?

Comment: Yes, but didn't work

Comment: Do you have the customer's name stored in a variable named `name`? The above code works fine for me.